# Synchronization cycles in swift

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety

Digita il testo o l'indirizzo di un sito web oppure traduci un documento.
I'm new in swift. I can not synchronize the work of two cycles and then display the results.

For example:

```
// Step1: do the first cycle.
for value0 in list0{
    doStuff()
}

// Step1: do the second cycle.
for value1 in list1{
    doStuff()
}

// Show result.

showResult()
```

I have tried to do this:

```
let lockQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.LockQueue", nil)
dispatch_sync(lockQueue) {
    // Step1: do the first cycle.
    for value0 in list0{
       doStuff()
    }

    // Step1: do the second cycle.
    for value1 in list1 {
       doStuff()
    }

    // Show result.
}
showResult()
```

It works and compiles but does not synchronize the work of the two codes. In fact shows the result not complete.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking. The source code that you have provided will execute sequentially; all `doStuff` calls related to `list0` will happen before all `doStuff` calls related to `list1`. Does your `doStuff` method push things onto a background queue?

Comment: Explain: I'm creating a .txt file where I write things. First I have to write things in list1 and ONLY when he finished I have to write things of list2 and ONLY when finished should show the result.

Comment: The code that you have written will do that unless your `doStuff` is pushing things to a different thread/dispatch queue. Without seeing the contents of `doStuff`, it is not clear why the code you have written does not already behave the way that you want.